# Live output from .jar executed by PHP

Tags: java, php, jar

I have a php-script which executes a .jar-file:

```
<?php
passthru("java -jar nlp-server.jar 9000");
?>
```

I want to display the output generated by this .jar-file on a website. The problematic part is the fact that the .jar-file doesnt finish executing because its a server-application.
Thus navigating to the php-file wont help and I didnt manage to make AJAX work either.

Is there a way to display the "live" output of the .jar-file on a website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use it directly via (if you can) : `<applet code="test.class" archive="nlp-server.jar" width=120 height=120>`

This is the only way I know because the (java) script must finish in order to display results via PHP else you will get execution timeout...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
system();
```

system() is just like the C version of the function in that it executes the given command and outputs the result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php